# JS - Set style of form input field from array

Tags: javascript

If i have saved all the fields in a form to an array,

```
var reqfield = document.getElementsByClassName("req");
```

how can i set the css style of a single field based on said array.

```
document.getElementById("myform")reqfield[1].style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Comment: Just remove the `document.getElementById("myform")` from `document.getElementById("myform")reqfield[1]`, why is it there? do you have many elements with that ID?

Answer (score 1):

You've already got the item stored in the array. It should just be

```
reqfield[1].style.backgroundColor = "red";
```